# jquery - iOS Safari video/camera not working on mobile device - Javascript and Html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Safari camera/video not working on a mobile device. It says error detected with the following parameters. is there any missing line to make safari browser camera/video works? because in desktop and android it works fine.

```
var mediaDevices = window.navigator.mediaDevices;
mediaDevices.getUserMedia = function(c) {
    return new Promise(function(y, n) {
 //This line is the error// (window.navigator.getUserMedia || window.navigator.mozGetUserMedia || window.navigator.webkitGetUserMedia).call(navigator, c, y, n);
    });
}


HTMLVideoElement.prototype.streamSrc = ('srcObject' in HTMLVideoElement.prototype) ? function(stream) 
{
    this.srcObject = !!stream ? stream : null;
} : function(stream) 
{
    if (!!stream) 
    {
        // this.src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(stream);
        // this.srcObject = stream;
        if (window.webkitURL) 
        {
            this.src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(stream);
        } 
        else 
        {
            this.src = stream;
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        this.removeAttribute('src');
    }
};
```